# What is Good Practice 'Error Handling' for Swift 4?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, error-handling, swift4

Please could someone guide me on a good practice using 'Error Handling' approaches with my 'working' (Swift 4) code below... (eg: 'Guards', 'Do', 'Catch', Throw', 'if', 'else')...

//// Import ////
import UIKit
import CoreData

//// Custom Function ////
func insertCoreData(){
    if let coreData = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {
        let data = MyEntity(entity: MyEntity.entity(), insertInto: coreData)
        data.name = "Joe Blogs"
        data.country = "United Kingdom"
        try? coreData.save()
        print("Data Saved...")
    }
}

//// Output Function ///
insertCoreData() // Working and Gives

Comment: I am unsure of the cleanness and simplest method of doing this as I am new to Swift (Please go easy).... I always work on the K.I.S.S rule... Many Thanks...

Comment: Unrelated but if `AppDelegate` is missing the app won't even launch and would discover a design error. It's pretty safe to force unwrap `as! AppDelegate`

Comment: Start by reading the Error Handling chapter in the Swift book.

Comment: Hi Both, I will look at that AppDelegate unwrap - Thanks.... I have started reading and using the Swift Handbook (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html ) But am wondering how other developers would approach this for this code... Thanks Both for the quick answers ;)

Comment: I typically build some abstraction on top of the db and network layers since they're usually async. I'll never make a direct database/network call from the UI thread. I'll use an abstraction layer that handles the various possible critical errors, and then send it back in callback function to the UI thread. In your example, you're squashing the error, so there will be no feedback to the user if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're heading for a lot of trouble if you're going to use ´try?´ for error handling, especially in a situation as crucial as saving your data.

Do yourself a big favour and use a proper do/try/catch (or re-throwing) as your standard way of handling error and only use try? or try! in very specific situations when you are aware of the consequences. It's more code to write but as soon as you have some kind of issue you'll appreciate the extra effort.

```
do {
  try coreData.save()
} catch {
  print("Unable to save Managed Object Context")
  print("\(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is the type of Error handle example I am looking for... But is that all I would need for the above code for "safe clean" Error handling ? Thanks ;)

Comment: @ChrisBrocklesby if you don't get a context (coreData == nil) then you probably want to log that and exit the app (although it is unlikely). fatalError(...) might do for a start but in the long run you should probably alert the user before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

Do,Try, Catch is a good start and it is the default implementation that Xcode loads for you during the CoreData setup.

At the same time it recommends you implement proper error handling for your app. Here are some of the reasons. By default it just prints the error message out.

```
   /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
```

There is a good video on Do, Try Catch by Sean Allen, showing an example of how to handle an error. Check it out.
[youtube - do, try, catch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lrc-MX8WgNc)